# How to Post an Object Data from mvc controller to web api Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-web-api, controller

Currently I'm just receiving a list of specific object but now I want a specific model or specific list of model, and also want a success message that data is saved or not.

Do you have any hints, I don't want to do it using ajax or json.

```
private static readonly string baseUri = "http://localhost:11033/api/values";

public List<ProductsModel> GetProducts()
{
    string uri = baseUri;
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        Task<String> response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync<List<ProductsModel>>(response.Result).Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note : Web-Api is separate from mvc project.

Answer (score 0):

You keep your code and you retrieve your `List<ProductsModel>` the same way. You can then use this list to set it as property of the `DTO` that you want to return from your `GetProducts()` Method - for example `GetProductsViewModel` which has three properties - `Succeeded = True/False`, `Message = "Error message if any"`, `Products = List<ProductsModel>` that you already have retrieved.